# Остановить выполнение макроса VBA

Tags: excel, vba, макросы, макрос

Возможно ли как-то остановить выполнение макроса без завершения процесса, если он, допустим, зашел в бесконечный цикл и вызвал зависание всего Excel?

Comment: Без кода как-то не очень  ясна ситуация и условия в которых возникает бесконечный цикл или вы говорите о любых вариантах когда нужна "серебряная пуля"?

Comment: Можно в цикле использовать DoEvents, тогда думаю его можно остановить без особых усилий. Если конечно речь об этом...

Comment: Для принудительной ручной остановки VBA-кода используется сочетание клавиш Ctrl-Break. Однако если в коде нет DoEvents, можно весьма долго ждать, пока это сочетание пробьётся к дебаггеру...

Comment: При написании/отладке *DoEvents*. Но в рабочем коде не должно быть возможности зацикливания. Наgример, проверка значения переменной: *If  bf=True Then Exit For*

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов контроля бесконечного цикла это контроль по времени. Т.е. задаем максимально допустимый интервал времени по истечение которого происходит выход из цикла. Например.

```
TimeInterval = 25 'секунд
t1 = Timer        ' задаем начальное время

Do                ' бесконечный цикл 
   tElepsed = Timer - t1
   If tElapsed > TimeInterval Then
       Exit Do
   End if

   'тело цикла
   '
Loop
```